# Geocode : converting doesn't work by submitting form

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocode

I have a form which converts an adress to geocode with the Google Map API using the onsubmit property. Since I know geocoding is asynchronous. Sometimes it works, and sometime it doesn't. Can anyone help me please? 
Thanks a lot!

jsp-file :

```
<body>
    <form name="addLocation" method="POST" action="addLocation.htm" commandName="location" onsubmit="changeAdress()">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value="${location.name}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Adress</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="adress" name="adress"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="geolocation" name="geolocation"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${location.id}"/>
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Save"/>
            <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

script :

```
    function changeAdress() {
        var adress = document.getElementById("adress").value; 
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': adress}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                document.addLocation.geolocation.value = latitude + " " + longitude;
                document.addLocation.submit();
            } else alert("geocode failed:" + status);
        });
        return false;
    }
```

You can allways try it yourself: http://jbossewss-leuvenspeaks.rhcloud.com/Test/newLocation.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the inline event handler, use a proper event handler, then prevent the form from submitting, and submit it programatically when the geocoder completes and the value is added to the form.

The `return false` in your code does not prevent the form from submitting btw.

```
document.getElementsByName('addLocation')[0].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self     = this;
    var adress   = document.getElementById("adress").value; 
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var geoloc   = document.getElementById("geolocation"); 

    geocoder.geocode({'address': adress}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude  = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            geoloc.value = latitude + " " + longitude;
            self.submit();
        } else {
            alert("geocode failed:" + status);
        }
    }); 
});
```